# 18.04 MATE Auto-accept all files when receiving by Bluetooth from device (phone)

Tags: bluetooth, blueman

### Background / use case

I photographed 24 paper documents with my Android phone. Each photo is around 8MB (I am planning to resize them later).

I marked all of them in my gallery app and used "share -> bluetooth" to send them to my Linux (Ubuntu Mate) computer.

I think the tool on Linux side is "blueman".

### Problem

On my Linux machine:

- I have to click "Accept" for each file separately.
- I have to wait until one file transaction is complete, before I can accept the next file.
- If I take too much time to accept one of the files, the entire operation fails.

This is a huge waste of time and attention.

### Question

Is there a way to automatically accept all files from a specific device, or from the same transaction?

### My system

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (bionic)
Distro: Ubuntu Mate
Desktop: Mate
No virtualization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the device to trusted.
Then in a terminal run `blueman-services`.
A window should open, here you can select "Transfers" -> "Accept incoming files from trusted devices".

Comment: Great, this works! Btw I found that the same dialog can be found in system tray icon "Local Services...".

Comment: good to know these solutions; but I wonder: why is that not accessible from blueman itself, where the "regular joe" use would expect it? Even if blueman would start blueman-services in turn, it's quite counter-intuitive to go searching for a second program to change the settings.